# Is ObjectContext deprecated in .NET 4.5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've been using `ObjectContexts` for quite a long time now. Now that I've installed VS 2012, for my surprise the Entity Data Model does not have an option for a Code Generation Item that creates `ObjectContexts` and `EntityObjects` instead of `DbContexts` and `POCOs`.

Is it deprecated now? I see the `ObjectContext` class is still available, but there's no way I can use it as the output of my EDMXs.

Comment: Lots of flux in EF.  It doesn't have anything to with the .NET version, EF is not part of the framework.  It's covered well by What's New: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant, it's not exactly right. Entity Framework is partially inside the .NET 4.5 (System.Data.Entity.dll) and partially outside (EntityFramework.dll). The designer, which belongs to System.Data.Entity, is completely bound to the .NET version

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ObjectContext is not deprecated. Actually DbContext is just a layer on top of ObjectContext. DbContext API has much nicer/smaller API and is easier to work with. Also POCO entities are much cleaner. This was the reason to change code generation. If you still want to use ObjectContext and EntityObject based entities remove *.tt files under the *.edmx file. Double click the edmx file to open it in the designer. Click on the designer surface. In the properties change "Code Generation Strategy" from "None" to "Default".

**EDIT**

The behavior has changed a bit in the EF6 designer that ships with VS2013 (and is available for download for VS2012). If you are using EF5 the two options are: 'T4' and 'LegacyObjectContext'. If you are using EF6 the dropdown is disabled. If you would like to use ObjectContext in an EF6 app you need to use [Entity Object generator for EF6](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/66612113-549c-4a9e-a14a-f629ceb3f89a) (note this link points just to one version of the template but there are actually a few versions depending on what you need - C# vs. VB.NET, WebSite non-WebSite - [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=EF%206.x&f%5B0%5D.Value=EF%206.x&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=2) is the list). You can find more details about changes in the EF6 tooling [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/).

Comment: Thanks. It's really strange that the "default" code generation strategy is not using any TT, and the default designer's modus operandi is to use DbContext TT. It would be clearer to me if it always used a TT and the default template had changed from ObjectContext to DbContext.

Comment: I agree it may be confusing. I think this is for historical reasons when in previous versions "default" meant without user's t4 files while "None" meant nothing because the user provides his own t4 templates. I also think that deafult actually uses t4 that are just not exposed.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft recommends the `EF5.x DbContext Generator` for new projects. It is the default template in VS2012. PreVS2012 users can find it using the ExtensionManager (search for EF5.x) or download it [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2).

You can of course still generate `EntityObjects` and `ObjectContext` by using the `EF4.x EntityObject Generator`template which can be found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e6db6554-345c-477a-9a73-3c5db06e9081).

How to set things up is described [here](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Unittesting-ADONET-Entity-Data-Models.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to make an EDMX generate using `ObjectContext`, but no it is not deprecated. `DbContext` is used because for 99% of users, the functionality of `ObjectContext` is not needed.

You can get a reference to an ObjectContext from a `DbContext`, though: `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that the ObjectContext was still accessible

Comment: I actually use ObjectContext because there are systems that use N-Tier systems, where I don't have access to the server connected to the database. So I can create an EDMX that interfaces with the application and the interface to the data server. ObjectContext fits very nicely when applied that way. Most people that use EF usually has a 2 tier system, which is why it's so common to use DBContext.