# Entity Framework 5 string predicate in methods

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, entity-framework-5

Well, I'm thinking this have been changed, but i'm thinking if i'm missing something.
When I upgrade my project to Framework 4.5 and EF5, i get a some errors.
I was checking and see that there's no string predicates in the "select", "where" method and others.

I have a query like this for example:

```
var res = _datos.TABLE.Select("it.id,it.name, it.age").Where("it.id == 5").First()
string name = res["name"].ToString();
int age = Convert.ToInt32(res["age"]);
```

Researching a little, a found a SqlQuery Method. Does EF5 change to this?
How can I select just the name and age in a specific table for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such methods have never existed.  Were you using dynamic LINQ?

Comment: yes, im using dynamic LINQ. but methods are unable to catch string query. Just lambda. (im half noob)

Comment: I set the Code Generation Strategy to Default and now I have the entities like it was.

Comment: If you target .NET Framework 4.5 you will get DbContext based context and POCO entities. If you target .NET Framework 4 you will get ObjectContext based context and EntityObject based entities. If you want these when targeting .NET Framework 4.5 change Code Generation Strategy to Default (as you did) and remove .tt files under edmx. Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609997/is-objectcontext-deprecated-in-net-4-5/13614390#comment18686599_13614390