# DbContext.SaveChanges() without any auto transaction handling

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to execute the DbContext.SaveChanges() without invoke its internal auto transaction handling?

I'm working to handle the transaction (DbTransaction) myself, but when I invoking it's Commit, I getting error "SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions"
I believe this is due to SaveChanges is doing its own internal transaction work, which I want to suppress it.

.NET 4.5, EntityFramework.dll ver 5.

googling shows few approaches, but the code are not compatible.
Some showing SaveChanges can accept a Boolean, which it is not in this ver. and then invoking AcceptAllChanges() which method also not exist.
While some is using System.Transaction.TransactionScope, but its different with this System.Data.Common.DbTransaction.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem, you have some problem X that you have not explained, you have a solution Y, which is to disable EF Default Transactions, and you can't figure out Y, but we don't know X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why are you doing a transaction outside of EntityFramework.

Comment: There are many circumstances you want to control the transaction manually. As being a framework, there should be an "intuitive" approach to manage that. Why shouldn't the EF allow such option? imo, it's an overlook, or design limitation.

Comment: *imo, it's an overlook, or design limitation*.  Quite the opposite.  When `SaveChanges()` is called, it is infinitely easier to code know that either everything EF did either did or did not work on the data store.  Without that, the amount of sheer code to keep the context *sync'd* with the data context would be insane (along with the great possibility of additional calls to the data store for verification).

Answer (score 1):

after many PITA efforts digging over the EF thing. the only way I found out to have proper transaction control over it is best to use ObjectContext, instead of DbContext.

http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/11320/entity-framework-savechanges-closes-connection

this hinted the ObjectContext

DbContext codebase is genereated if your EDMX code generation strategy is set to None.

link: [Is ObjectContext deprecated in .NET 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609997/is-objectcontext-deprecated-in-net-4-5)

by changing it to Default, you will get ObjectContext code base gen.

the diff of them so far of what I found out, using DbContext, whenever you invoke its SaveChanges(), it will AUTO close the underneath connection, and your next db task will have a new connection, which basically break the transaction control of what I seek.
you need to run the whole db tasks without the conx being close or recreate within the transaction.

by using ObjectContext, SaveChanges() will not auto close the connection if I setup the transaction and connection codes properly before it.